# Reg - QTP - Automation Batch Run

Tags: qtp

I have some doubts on Automation batch run through QTP and Quality center. In a case where I have 50-100 Automation Tests running in Batch in a Test Set in a Test lab in quality center:

1. When we start the batch run, is it possible to run both "Application under Test",QTP and QC in hidden mode. If yes, how to make all of them hidden mode?
2. When the Automation Tests are running in sequence in visible mode, could we use the same computer for other activities? or will it move away the focus of the application?
3. When the automation tests are running and if System goes to Locked or sleep mode, will the automation test keeps running or will it get stopped.
4. Any other do and don'ts in automation batch run please kindly share with me.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question 1: It believe no.** Depending on the GUI technical details, it might be possible to execute the AUT on a separate desktop, or even WinStation, but neither QTP nor anything else is build to support that afaik.

Knowing all the subtle details that one has to pay attention to if for example QTP and the AUT are running in a remote desktop session makes be believe that it is not a feasible goal to hide or execute the triple on a machine that you want to use interactively during test execution. See answer to 2.

So why don´t you buy a good old hardware monitor & keyboard switch, and connect a separate machine exclusively for test execution? You would never need to touch it if test execution is managed by QC.

**Answer to question 2: Maybe. There are some GUI interfaces that QTP can playback to without the target window having the focus (Web with "event" playback mode as opposed to "mouse").**

You would, however, need to gain focus at least once since the first playback would focus the AUT.
I tried using a machine interactively that executes QTP tests in the background. **It is not a good idea.** You just interfere way too easy with the AUT accidentally. Or QTP grabs your window focus.

**Answer to question 3:**

**Locked mode: Usually breaks synchronization between QTP and the AUT because,** QTP looses access to the GUI.

**Sleep mode: I don't know.**